# LibGDX - find out if a given screen resolution is supported on the current device

Tags: java, libgdx, lwjgl

So I'm writing some tools for my program to deal with basic configurations, reading settings from a data file, and then making those settings the active configuration. I'm also building in an error checking mechanism to make sure that settings are formatted correctly and have valid values.

I want to check to see what the current devices supported resolutions are, and I want to compare that to the resolution specified in the data file. Is there an easy way to do this in libGDX that I'm missing? I know that LWJGL has a function that will give you an array of the supported resolutions, but I don't want to reinvent the wheel.

I'm looking for something like:
boolean isValidResolutionForDevice(int width, int height)

Am I going to have to write this myself? Or does this exist already? It seems to me to be such a useful function that it must have been written into the libraries somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no ready solution in libgdx, I solved it like this:

```
    private Map<Integer, Integer> supportedReolutions;
    private String graphicFolder;

    supportedReolutions = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
    supportedReolutions.put(1024, 768);
    supportedReolutions.put(1080, 1920);
    supportedReolutions.put(1200, 1920);
    supportedReolutions.put(2048, 1536);
    supportedReolutions.put(480, 800);
    supportedReolutions.put(640, 1136);
    graphicFolder = "1080x1920";

/**
 * Chose the folder with best graphic for current device
 */
private void setCurrentResolutionFolder() {
    int width = Gdx.graphics.getWidth();
    int height = Gdx.graphics.getHeight();
    if (supportedReolutions.containsKey(width)) {
        if (supportedReolutions.get(width) == height) {
            graphicFolder = String.valueOf(width) + "x"
                    + String.valueOf(height);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I like this solution, but what is the term folder? Do you mean a physical file directory?

Edit: Ah yes I see what you've done here. Yeah this looks good. Then you can just get the list of supported resolutions from LWJGL.

Answer (score 3):

There actually is a way to do this. The main `com.badlogic.gdx.Application` interface has a `getGraphics()` method, and the `com.badlogic.gdx.Graphics` class returned from that has `getDisplayModes()` method, which returns `DisplayMode[]`. `DisplayMode` basically looks like this (comments and constructor removed):

```
public class DisplayMode {
    /** the width in physical pixels **/
    public final int width;
    /** the height in physical pixles **/
    public final int height;
    /** the refresh rate in Hertz **/
    public final int refreshRate;
    /** the number of bits per pixel, may exclude alpha **/
    public final int bitsPerPixel;
}
```

And then you can scan through these to see if the resolution in question is supported or not.

The only bit of annoying news is because `getGraphics()` is on the Application object, it doesn't seem like you can query for the available graphics modes until *after* the Application object (e.g. `LwjglApplication`) has been created. So perhaps you pick an arbitrary resolution (e.g. 1024x768), start the game, then immediately switch to a supported resolution if the original wasn't actually supported (and optionally let the user pick in a settings menu).

---

I came across the method I believe you're referring to, `org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.getAvailableDisplayModes()`, and...honestly I'd just use this one for your use case. You'd pretty much just be iterating over it with a simple conditional inside. Not exactly reinventing anything.

Comment: The OP is a two year old post that's been answered already. We're not even talking remotely about the same version anymore.

Comment: I'm aware it's an old post. I thought I'd provide a correct answer in case other people also had the same question.

Comment: Ah ok. Yeah I hear ya.